# Updating an App - Changing Core Data Model - Test scenario

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval, data-migration

I was wondering, how to test your App if you change your data model and need to do data migration. There are some questions here on how to do the latter but I was wondering how to make sure it works.

Is that possible in any way?

Also, it seems, that the process of installing an update seems to differ from the App Review, since Apps are not tested for crashes if the data model is changed. Can someone explain this process to me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well we what we do is, install the current version (from the appstore).
The just test (via XCode debugger) the new build on the phone.
This way you can debug the problem better then just installing the new IPA.

So to test if the migration is working, install a previous version of the app (ex. the app store version).
Then debug the new version, with the updated model, on you iPhone. By running it via XCode.
This will hookup the debugger which will allow you to seen what is going on.

If this runs perfectly, you have successfully update your model, you can check if the data is still intact by downloading the app data via the organizer.

The remove the app and check if a fresh install works.

We have see that the review process will test the build as a new build, never as an update.
Not stating that this can not happen, nu has not happened yet.

Comment: Im not sure if I understand this correct. Would you elaborate on this a little more?